# Performance task in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, performance

We have IT olimpics in my country. Normally they are written in Java, C or C++. I gues for a year or so they also include other languages like python. 
I tried to solve a task from previous years in Python called Letters and I'm constantly failing. The task is to write a code that counts minimum number of shifts between neighboring letters to turn one string into another.

As input you get number of letters in one string and two strings with same amount of letters but in different order. Lenght of one string is from 2 to 1 000 000 letters. There are only capital letters,  they can but don't have to be sorted and can repeat.

Here's an example:
7
AABCDDD
DDDBCAA

Correct output should be 16

As output you have to return single value which is minimum number of shifts. It has to calculate output under 5seconds.
I made it calculate correct output, but in longer strings (lik 800 000 letters) it starts to slow down. The longest inputs return value in about 30 seconds. There's also one input counting 900 000 letters per word that calculates 30 minutes!

Under link you can find all input files for tests:
https://oi.edu.pl/l/19oi_ksiazeczka/

Click on this link to download files for "Letters" task:
XIX OI testy i rozwiązania - zad. LIT (I etap) (3.5 MB)

Bellow is my code. How can I speed it up?

```
# import time
import sys

# start = time.time()
def file_reader():
    standard_input=""
    try:
        data = sys.stdin.readlines()
        for line in data:
            standard_input+=line
    except:
        print("An exception occurred")
    return standard_input
def mergeSortInversions(arr):
    if len(arr) == 1:
        return arr, 0
    else:
        a = arr[:len(arr)//2]
        b = arr[len(arr)//2:]
        a, ai = mergeSortInversions(a)
        b, bi = mergeSortInversions(b)
        c = []
        i = 0
        j = 0
        inversions = 0 + ai + bi
    while i < len(a) and j < len(b):
        if a[i] <= b[j]:
            c.append(a[i])
            i += 1
        else:
            c.append(b[j])
            j += 1
            inversions += (len(a)-i)
    c += a[i:]
    c += b[j:]
    return c, inversions
def literki():
    words=(file_reader()).replace("\n", "")
    number = int("".join((map(str, ([int(i) for i in list(words) if i.isdigit()])))))
    all_letters = [x for x in list(words) if x not in str(number)]
    name = all_letters[:number]
    anagram = all_letters[number:]
    p=[]
    index=list(range(len(anagram)))
    anagram_dict = {index[i]: anagram[i] for i in range(len(index))} 

    new_dict = {} 
    anagram_counts={}
    for key, value in anagram_dict.items(): 
        if value in new_dict: 
            new_dict[value].append(key) 
        else: 
            new_dict[value]=[key] 
    for i in new_dict: 
        anagram_counts.update({i:new_dict[i]})
    for letter in name:
        a=anagram_counts[letter]
        p.append(a.pop(0))
    print(mergeSortInversions(p)[1])
#>>
literki()   

# end = time.time()
# print(start-end)
```

So to explain what it does in parts: File_reader: simply reads an input file from standard input. mergeSortInversions(arr): normally it would sort a string, but here I wanted it to return sum of inversions. I'm not that smart to figure it out by myself, I found it on web but it does the job. Unfortunatelly, for 1mln strings it does that in 10 secondes or so. In "literki" function: first, I've devided input to have number of signs and two, even in lenght words as lists.

Then, I've made something similar in function to stacks array (not shure if it is called this way in english). basically I made a dictionary with every letter as key and indexes of those letters as a list in values (if a letter occurs more than once, value would contain a list of all indexes for that letter). Last thing I did before "the slow thing", for every letter in "name" variable I've extracted coresponding index. Up to that point all opertations for every input, ware taking arround 2 secconds. And now two lines that generate the rest of time for calculating outcome: - I append the index to p=[] list and in the same time pop it from list in dictionary, so it wouldn't read it again for another same letter. - I calculate number of moves (inversions) with mergeSortInversions(arr) based on p=[...] list and print it as output.

I know that poping from bottom is slow but on the other hand I would have to create lists of indexes from bottom (so I could pop index from top) but that took even longer. I've also tried converting a=[... ] with deque but it also was to slow.

Comment: This sounds like a task for dynamic programming!  I haven't dug into your code, but it could be useful to describe your approach rather than just pasting in a block of code that people have to look through to understand.  That way people can let you know if you are on the right path or not.

Answer (score 0):

I think I'd try a genetic algorithm for this problem.  GA's don't always come up with an optimal solution, but they are very good for getting an acceptable solution in a reasonable amount of time.  And for small inputs, they can be optimal.

The gist is to come up with:
1) A fitness function that assigns a number indicating how good a particular candidate solution is
2) A sexual reproduction function, that combines, in a simple way, part of two candidate solutions
3) A mutation function, that introduces one small change to a candidate solution.

So you just let those functions go to town, creating solution after solution, and keeping the best ones - not the best one, the best *ones*.

Then after a while, the best solution found is your answer.

Here's an example of using a GA for another hard problem, called The House Robber Problem. It's in Python:
http://stromberg.dnsalias.org/~strombrg/house-robber-problem/